# how to calculate rise over run value by given angle with iPhone device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, xcode5

hello i am calculating the device angle by fallowing code and then converting this angle to rise over run formula i am getting the wrong pitch value but when i start rotating device(left to right and right to left in landscape mode) then after some time i started to get correct pitch value here is my code....

```
operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 2.0 / 60.0;
    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdates];

    [motionManager startDeviceMotionUpdatesUsingReferenceFrame:CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical toQueue:operationQueue
                                                        withHandler:^(CMDeviceMotion *motion, NSError *error)
    {
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            CGFloat x = motion.gravity.x;
            CGFloat y = motion.gravity.y;
            CGFloat z = motion.gravity.z;
            CGFloat angle = atan2(y, x) + M_PI_2;           // in radians
            CGFloat angleDegrees = angle * 180.0f / M_PI;   // in degrees
            CGFloat r = sqrtf(x*x + y*y + z*z);


            CMQuaternion quat = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.quaternion;
            NSNumber *myroll = [NSNumber numberWithInt:radiansToDegrees(atan2(2*(quat.y*quat.w - quat.x*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.y*quat.y - 2*quat.z*quat.z))];

            NSNumber *mypitch = [NSNumber numberWithInt:radiansToDegrees(atan2(2*(quat.x*quat.w + quat.y*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.x*quat.x - 2*quat.z*quat.z))];

            NSNumber *myyaw = [NSNumber numberWithInt:radiansToDegrees(2*(quat.x*quat.y + quat.w*quat.z))];

            //double actualYaw = [myyaw doubleValue];
           // CGFloat tiltForwardBackward = ceilf(motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.yaw * 180 / M_PI);

            **strong text**float pitchValue = motionManager.deviceMotion.attitude.pitch;
            pitchValue = [mypitch doubleValue];
            pitchValue = (pitchValue < 0) ? -(pitchValue) : pitchValue;
            float pitchAngle = [mypitch doubleValue];

            pitchAngle = (pitchAngle < 0) ? -(pitchAngle) : pitchAngle;

            //pitchValue = (tan(pitchValue*(M_PI/180))*12);

            **strong text**pitchValue = (tan((pitchValue*M_PI)/180))*12; // i am using this formula to calculate roof pitch value.

            pitchValue = (pitchValue < 0) ? -(pitchValue) : pitchValue;
            if(pitchValue >= 99.9){
                pitchValue = 99.9;
            }
            deviceAngle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Pitch Value = %0.1f/12, Pitch Angle = %.2f", pitchValue, pitchAngle];
            //deviceAngle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @" %.1f/12",pitchValue];

        }];
    }];
```

please help is there any way to calculate rise over run value by using any of this three value.i am keeping my iPhone in landscape mode and then rotating left to right and right to left.
am using wrong value?.i am interested to calculate roof pitch value.is there any formula?.
please help me thanks in advance.